# Modification on animate script?

Tags: jquery, animation

I found this post which is a tutorial to animate elements on scroll: [Tutorial for animated scroll loading effects with Animate.css and jQuery | web2feel.com](http://www.web2feel.com/tutorial-for-animated-scroll-loading-effects-with-animate-css-and-jquery/)

It works great, in the article example the divs with the class: "post" are shown when you reach them when scrolling.

I'd like to change this js to make that if 2 divs are shown at the same time then the script animates one after another (not both at the same time). Below the js that shows the 2 divs are shown at the same time. I need to put a pause beetwen them.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
        classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
        offset: 100
    });
});
```

Comment: you only have 2 `.post`s?

Comment: no, I have 5 rows of 2 .post, total: 10 .post. But it could be more or less. Why is this important?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I would be tempted to make two different classes for the two divs. `.post` and `.postafter`. Assuming we have some html like so...

```
<style>
    .post, .postafter{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 49%;
    }
</style>

<section>
    <div class="post"> Text or images here ... </div>
    <div class="postafter"> More along side ... </div>
</section>
<section>
    ... repeated down the page ...
</section>
```

You could then do something like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/4LKeg/1/) where the two different divs load at different scroll offsets.

```
jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
    offset: 100
});

jQuery('.postafter').addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
    classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
    offset: 200
});
```

Or you could do something more like this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Klors/4LKeg/) where they load at the same offset but after a delay for the second by adding to one of the class's CSS rules...

```
.postafter {
    -webkit-animation-delay: 0.5s;
    ... other vendor specific rules ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this can be acheived by using setTimeout javascript function as shown below.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function () {
 timer = 0;
     jQuery('.post'), each(function () { //deal with each post instead of all in one go.
        setTimeout(function () {
             $(this).addClass("hidden").viewportChecker({
                 classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
                 offset: 100
             });
         }, timer);
         timer = 1000; // this will delay second execution by 1 sec.
     });
 });
```

Not tested but should work if you only have two elements of class `post`.

Answer (score 0):

I have only read your question but didn't go to your tutorial source, so using only the detail you have provided, here's how you may go about getting the result you desire:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // ...

    // my guess is that viewportChecker(...) does the actual animation,
    // so it should be called later for each post.
    var posts = jQuery('.post').addClass("hidden");

    // now call viewportChecker(...) on each post, sequentially...
    jQuery.each(posts, function(post, index){
        post.viewportChecker({
            classToAdd: 'visible animated fadeIn',
            offset: 100
        });
    });
});
```

If the frame of overlap in the animation is too lengthy, then you may queue subsequent indices after the first in a timeout.

Good luck.